# Web Scraping with VBA - Almost There

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

After studying many posts here, i finally patched together code that worked (below)! It extracts the index value from yahoo finance when the index is basically the only data point on the page (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EHSI?p=%5EHSI&.tsrc=fin-srch).

However, when I want the same index from a website containing several index values (https://www.hkex.com.hk/?sc_lang=en), the web code looks overwhelming for me to correctly reference the element and put into my coding. Can anyone please help with this final hurdle? Thank you.
[image]

```
Sub HSI_Scrape()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False

IE.Navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EHSI?p=%5EHSI&.tsrc=fin-srch"

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Dim hsi As String
hsi = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")(0).innerText

Worksheets("Tickers").Select
Range("z11").value = hsi
```

End Sub

Comment: What you might find helpful (I really enjoyed them) are the [wise owl web-scraping tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/user/WiseOwlTutorials/search?query=web-scraping) - they cover all the basics and the instructor is a former teacher and that experience really shows. Then spend some time doing as basic html course. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB1O30fR-EE) one is perfect entry level especially as html at first can seem very alien. The same guy does a CSS and JavaScript crash course (they all assume  little to no prior experience) for later reading if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the tickers on HKEX has class "listitem". So to get each ticker, search for that class using getElementsByClassName("listitem"). Loop through each element, and the first child (class="col_name") of the element will be the ticker name, the second child (class="col_last") will be the price.

```
Sub HSI_Scrape()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False

    IE.Navigate "https://www.hkex.com.hk/?sc_lang=en"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Dim listitems As Object 'list of tickers
    Dim listitem As Object  'each ticker
    Set listitems = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("listitem")
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    For Each listitem In listitems
        Worksheets("Tickers").Range("A" & row) = listitem.Children(0).innerText 'Ticker Name
        Worksheets("Tickers").Range("B" & row) = listitem.Children(1).innerText 'Ticker Price
        row = row + 1
    Next listitem
End Sub
```

Comment: This is it!  So i can't directly reference the item in a single line but need to create this loop to progress through each "class". Fantastic. Thank you OmerA!!!